# Recommended guideline for sharing videos that is meant to be viewed by others

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to work on video sharing/feed app similar to Instagram. My question is how about the design decision behind shared video. Basically, I am wondering how the videos load so fast.

Basically when device A uploads video to the server and Device B views it, does the video being uploaded have the same frame size across all devices (do they force certain size)? Do they compress or use a certain format?

I don't want my question to be broad. So I just want to know what would be the recommended guideline for a video that is meant to be shared/viewed using Exoplayer? I imagine  I have control over
Frame size
Video format
other?

Thank you

Comment: *"I don't want my question to be broad."* - Hmm ... so perhaps you should have asked a question that isn't so broad.

Comment: This is is exactly why that statement was followed by concise question  to limit the broadens and focus on what I am trying to understand. I dont think I can get it more particular than this

Comment: *"So I just want to know what would be the recommended guideline for a video that is meant to be shared/viewed using Exoplayer?"* ... is not a concise question.  It is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering how the videos load so fast.

Simply by running or using a content delivery service with a lot of capacity to deliver content.

They don't do it by doing adjusting frame rates or resolution on the fly.   It is too computationally expensive and will slow down delivery.   If they server up multiple resolutions or frame rates the recoding will be done ahead of time.

They don't do it by compressing on the fly.  Any compression will be done ahead of time.  Besides, typical video formats are already compressed, so an extra compression step will have no benefit.

Comment: Thanks so if they do it ahead of time ( that's an option I can do ) how does it look the same in every phone given a lot of phone screen sizes ? Is there a certain size i should aim for